# Update a table column using a mapping table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have three tables: a, b, c. **Table b** is a *mapping* table for **table a** and **table c**. I am trying to update **table a column = table c column**.

When implementing the update, I receive an error:

> [S0001][4104] The multi-part identifier could not be bound

```
UPDATE table_a
SET table_a.Sector = table_c.Sector
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
  ON table_a.business_ID = cast(table_b.business_id as BIGINT)
INNER JOIN table_c
  ON table_b.ACARA_SML_ID = table_c.ACARA_SML_ID
WHERE a.State = 'ABC';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UPDATE statement directly from SELECT clause :

```
 UPDATE table_a SET table_a.Sector = C.Sector
 FROM table_c C
 WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT 1 FROM table_b B B.ACARA_SML_ID = C.ACARA_SML_ID AND 
              table_a.business_ID = CAST(B.business_id AS BIGINT)
 ) AND A.[STATE] = 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `WHERE` clause you are using `a.State`, here `a` was not set as table alias for any of the table.

Can you try this query with correct table alias:

```
UPDATE A
SET Sector = C.Sector
FROM table_a A
INNER JOIN table_b B ON A.business_ID = CAST(B.business_id AS BIGINT)
INNER JOIN table_c C ON B.ACARA_SML_ID = C.ACARA_SML_ID
WHERE A.[STATE] = 'ABC';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When implementing the original script I was using an alias, but still received the same error.

Comment: Can you change the `set` statement as `SET Sector = C.Sector` and try?

Comment: Can you please recheck the tables and columns you are using in the query, I believe the query is correct but the columns referred are incorrect

Comment: I did try it as per request. I got it working using the user's solution below.

Comment: @mathew.sayed So you meant, the answer is working fine?

Comment: @Arulkumar I did, not with your solution. With your solution I still received the same error.